# Set navigation item title of a view from another view that calls it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

Here I have 2 views: **userProfileVC** and **userListVC**.
In **userProfileVC**, there is a button action method:

```
- (IBAction)followingButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UserListViewController *userListViewController = [[UserListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    userListViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    userListViewController.navItem.title = @"Followings"; //I expect this to set userListVC navigation item title to "Followings"
    [self presentViewController:userListViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This will call **userListVC** which I have set a property of navItem as below:

*UserListVC.h*

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

*UserListVC.m*

```
@synthesize navItem;
```

My problem is why navigation item title in userListVC is not shown "Followings" according to what I have set in userProfileVc (see my comment in the first code) but it results nothing to the title. I don't know what I have done wrong or missing here.

Comment: My guess is that `userListViewController.navItem` is `nil`, because you have declared it as a `weak` property. Check that with a breakpoint or log statement.

Comment: I logged navItem.title in userListVC's viewDidLoad. It shows null.

Comment: The property **navItem** declared as **strong** doesn't help.

Comment: if you want the title to show up in the navigation bar you should set the (NSString *)title property on the UIViewController ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing

```
userListViewController.navItem.title = @"Followings";
```

in your code above to

```
userListViewController.title = @"Followings";
```

UIViewController has a (NSString *)title property.  If this is not nil then this is the string you'll see in the UINavigationBar when that particular UIViewController is up front.

then change this

```
[self presentViewController:userListViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

to this

```
if (self.navigationController){
[self.navigationController presentViewController:userListViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}else{
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:userListViewController];
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
```

Comment: First off, what do you mean by setting (NSString *)title property on the UIViewController? Except that, I tried the change you said but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok well you should be using a UINavigationController to present it?  I'll edit my answer.  Also FYI you should not have to declare a property of type UINavigationItem on your viewController, they already have a property of this type for your convenience..